# How to have Hibernate drop and recreate database during runtime, not at compile time?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I have a webserver and am prototyping some work with hibernate and spring. I have a Insert method that inserts a bunch of test data. This script kicks off when a certain page on my website is requested by the user. I would like to have the DB dropped and recreated when the user enters this page.

Is there anyway to do this at run time like I am suggesting? I can stop and start my server, but that takes a while.

Update - Here is how I did it:

```
    Configuration configuration = new Configuration().configure();
    ServiceRegistry serviceRegistry = new ServiceRegistryBuilder().applySettings(configuration.getProperties()).buildServiceRegistry();
    SchemaExport schemaExport = new SchemaExport(serviceRegistry, configuration);
    schemaExport.create(Target.BOTH);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `SchemaExport` hibernate class directly, have a look at the [javadoc](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.2/javadocs/org/hibernate/tool/hbm2ddl/SchemaExport.html).

This is the same class internally called by hibernate when you set parameter `hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=create-drop`. Dropping and creating the schema can be triggered with `dropSchema()` and `createSchema()`.